# Текст в полях формы (скрипт jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Для того, чтобы в инпуте pleceholder был кроссбраузерным, вместо него значение поля задается атрибутом value, которое при клике убирается скриптом

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //placeholder in input
        $('.addComments form input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
            $('.addComments form input[type="text"]').attr('value', '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

скрипт работает, если в форме одно поле, но если полей несколько, то значения удаляются из всех полей одновременно http://jsfiddle.net/WK5bA/3/.
Подскажите, как дописать этот скрипт, чтобы значение убиралось только у того поля, на которое кликнуто мышкой?

Comment: @Heidel, я попытался облегчить вам страдания :) http://jsfiddle.net/WK5bA/5/ (необходимо проверить на кроссбраузерность)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.addComments form input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr('value', ''); //ссылаемся на активный элемент $(this)
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: какой хороший вариант, ничего лишнего! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.addComments form input[type="text"]').focus(function(){this.value=''});
```

Answer (score 0):

В input добавляете id='example'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example').focus(function() {
            $('#example').attr('value', '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

P.S. Т.е. для каждого поля свое id :)

Comment: нет, это получается три идентичных скрипта для каждого инпута, это как-то неправильно.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения... что-то я перегрелся уже на работе :)